# Create-react-app + react-app-rewired + typescript + antd

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, antd

I'm trying to get a project started and having trouble. Has anybody had any success getting Create-react-app + react-app-rewired + typescript + antd working together? I've tried about every tutorial/custom scripts/loader thing out there with no luck. I thought https://github.com/SZzzzz/react-scripts-ts-antd would be the answer to all my problems but getting this compiling error:

`(28,81): Type '{ className: string; style: { transition: string | boolean; msTransform: string; WebkitTransform:...' does not satisfy the constraint 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>'.
  Types of property 'style' are incompatible.
    Type '{ transition: string | boolean; msTransform: string; WebkitTransform: string; transform: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties | undefined'.
      Type '{ transition: string | boolean; msTransform: string; WebkitTransform: string; transform: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
        Types of property 'transition' are incompatible.
          Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
            Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.`

Answer (score 11):

> init

```
    create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts
    cd my-app
    yarn add antd 
    yarn add react-app-rewired ts-import-plugin --dev
```

> add `config-overrides.js`

```
    const {
        getLoader,
        injectBabelPlugin
    } = require("react-app-rewired");
    const tsImportPluginFactory = require('ts-import-plugin')

    module.exports = function override(config, env) {
        // do stuff with the webpack config...
        const tsLoader = getLoader(
            config.module.rules,
            rule =>
            rule.loader &&
            typeof rule.loader === 'string' &&
            rule.loader.includes('ts-loader')
        );

        tsLoader.options = {
            getCustomTransformers: () => ({
                before: [
                    tsImportPluginFactory([{
                        libraryDirectory: 'es',
                        libraryName: 'antd',
                        style: 'css',
                    }]),
                ]
            })
        };

        return config;
    };
```

> update `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start --scripts-version react-scripts-ts",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build --scripts-version react-scripts-ts",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom --scripts-version react-scripts-ts",
    "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject"
  },
```